# This vertical Navigation menu conatiner is'nt poping?

Tags: html, css

Here is the menu navigation bar ! you can put up and check this but it is'nt showing anything !
This is showing the navigation bar and upon mouse hover there is no popup box as defined !

Im using it in a conatiner, will that be any problem ?

```
<style type="text/css">
#twiz-vtab-wrapper {
min-height: 185px;
min-width: 200px;
display: block;
float: left;
}
.twiz_vtabm {
min-height: 21px;
border: 1px solid #000000;
display: block;
padding: 10px;
}
.twiz_vtabm:hover {
cursor: pointer;
background-color: #000000 !important;
color: #ffffff !important;
}
.twiz_vtabm_selected {
background-color: #000000;
color: #ffffff;
}
.twiz_vtab_box {
min-height: 185px;
width: 495px;
background-color: #ebebeb;
border: 1px solid #000000;
padding: 15px;
display: none;
float: left;
}
.twiz_vtab_clear {
height: 0px;
clear: both;
}
</style>
<div class="twiz_vtab_clear"></div>
<div id="twiz-vtab-wrapper">
<div id="twiz-vtabm-1" class="twiz_vtabm">Tab Menu 1</div>
<div id="twiz-vtabm-2" class="twiz_vtabm">Tab Menu 2</div>
<div id="twiz-vtabm-3" class="twiz_vtabm">Tab Menu 3</div>
<!-- Paste new code #1 here -->
</div>
<div id="twiz-vtab-box-1" class="twiz_vtab_box">
Your HTML here.
<ul><li>Box 1</li></ul>
</div>
<div id="twiz-vtab-box-2" class="twiz_vtab_box">
Your HTML here.
<ol><li>Box 2</li><li>Box 2</li></ol>
</div>
<div id="twiz-vtab-box-3" class="twiz_vtab_box">
Your HTML here.
<ul><li>Box 3</li><li>Box 3</li><li>Box 3</li></ul>
</div>
<!-- Paste new code #2 here -->
<div class="twiz_vtab_clear"></div>
```

Comment: im confused of your question?? what would you like it to be??

Comment: It must be in this way !
http://www.sebastien-laframboise.com/free-simple-vertical-tab-menu/ 
But, it is in this way http://jsfiddle.net/PpuQP/

Comment: sorry so long to reply. im at work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the answer. i tried to edit the work and add jquery for it.

http://jsfiddle.net/RgDRm/

Hope it helped